# Getting "No route matches [GET]" error in spite of defining my link_to as a "post"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my controller:

```
view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@course.versions.last), :method => :post)
```

And the following route:

```
post 'versions/:id/revert' => 'versions#revert', as: "revert_version"
```

I get the following error:
`No route matches [GET] "/versions/16/revert"`

The error does not occur if I change the method type to `get`

PS: I'm following this [RailsCast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L8fdZMRWLQ).

Comment: Do you mind to run the following command and post its output: `rake routes | grep revert`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you didn't disable javascript? From [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)  documentation:

"Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET"

It seems that `method: :post` is not being respected.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. I'm able to open modals and confirmation dialogues.

Comment: where are you using that `view_context`?

Comment: Also, verify if the generated anchor has the data-method attribute and if you are requiring jquery_ujs in your manifest.

Comment: I am using jquery_ujs. How do I verify the generated anchor? Thanks!

Comment: right click over the page, and select 'view page source'. If you are using chrome,  you can also select  'Inspect' option.

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming that you're trying to click over that link on your webpage. If not, please post the relevant controller code.

Comment: I get this `<a href="/versions/53/revert">undo</a>`. I am trying to click the link on the webpage. I'm doing this:
      undo_link = view_context.link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@course.versions.last), method: :post)

      flash[:success] = "Updated course's details: " + get_flash_link(@course) + ". #{undo_link}"

      redirect_to :back

Comment: Could you try to add the link_to directly to the view and see if you get the data-method attribute? `<%= link_to("undo", revert_version_path(@course.versions.last), :method => :post) %>`. Which rails version are you using?